# Perl Search and Replace in one regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I need in something like this: `'s/oldstr/newstr/g;pattern'`, i.e. I want to replace `oldstr` and find some `pattern` in the string after replace. All in one regular expression.

Comment: I guess if the pattern has nothing to do with the replace it makes sense. Like, change the string and match the result against a more complicated pattern.

Comment: with `s/oldstr/newstr/g`? Nothing.

Comment: why all in one regular expression?  show complete sample input and what result you want?

Comment: You pretty much can't do that, but why would you want to do so anyway?  Perl can be cryptic enough without adding such contortions to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace first and look for a pattern in the resulting string, you can just put both expressions after one another. The replace with the `/r` flag will return the altered string, and the `m` operator will match that string against the pattern.

```
use Test::Simple 'no_plan'; # this is just for the ok() function

my $str = 'foobar';
ok($str =~ s/o/0/gr =~ m/\d\d/);
ok($str =~ s/o/0/gr !~ m/\d\d\d/);

__END__
ok 1
ok 2
1..2
```

Comment: Technically, that's two regexes in each case, but it is about as close to what he wants as the OP is likely to get. I'm not sure it wins any marks for readability, but that's not your fault.

Comment: Yeah, I know. And I'm not claiming to make it readable either. :)